# Variable not shared in extended class using Java

Tags: java

I'm creating a basic concurrent server allowing a user to download a file using *Java NIO*. Prior to downloading the user must accept the terms and conditions.

The problem appears to be that my `state` variable is not being updated in my `ServerProtocol` class despite updating it in my `Terms` class.  Are these variables not shared when extending a class?

```
public class ServerProtocol {

    private static final int TERMS = 0;
    public static final int ACCEPTTERMS = 1;
    private static final int ANOTHER = 2;
    private static final int OPTIONS = 3;
    public int state = TERMS;

    public String processInput(String theInput) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String theOutput = null;

        switch (state) {
            case TERMS:
                theOutput = terms();
                break;
            case ACCEPTTERMS:
                ........
}

 private String terms() {
        String theOutput;
        theOutput = "Terms of reference. Do you accept? Y or N ";
        state = ACCEPTTERMS;

        return theOutput;
    }
```

In the above scenario, the user enters Y or N corresponding to `theOutput` string and the state is set to `ACCEPTTERMS` and executes the code within.  That works fine.

However, I wanted to separate concerns and create a class to hold the terms and conditions and other related methods.

I produce the following:

```
public class ServerProtocol {

    public static final int TERMS = 0;
    public static final int ACCEPTTERMS = 1;
    public static final int ANOTHER = 2;
    public static final int OPTIONS = 3;
    public int state = TERMS;

    public String processInput(String theInput) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String theOutput = null;
        Terms t = new Terms();

        switch (state) {
            case TERMS:
                theOutput = t.terms();
                state = ACCEPTTERMS;  // I want to remove this line //
                break;
            case ACCEPTTERMS:
                .......
}      

public class Terms extends ServerProtocol {

    private String theOutput;
    private static final String TERMS_OF_REFERENCE = "Terms of reference. Do you accept? Y on N ";

    public String terms() {
        theOutput = termsOfReference();
        // state = ACCEPTTERMS;    // and add it here //
        return theOutput;
    }

    public String termsOfReference() {
        return TERMS_OF_REFERENCE;
    }
```

The result:

A continuous loop of the `terms()` method and the state not being set to `ACCEPTTERMS` in the `ServerProtocol` class.  I presume that despite extended the `ServerProtocol` class, the `ACCEPTTERMS` variable is not shared.  Any ideas why?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying the problem is; if ACCEPTTERMS wasn't "shared" you wouldn't be able to compile. Are you saying `state` isn't updated?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes. 'State' isn't being updated.  Thanks for the correction

Comment: Also, it's not clear to me why `Terms` is a subclass; it seems a bit weird that you're instantiating a subclass of the current class in order to do work. I'd probably consider something else.

Comment: @DaveNewton  The main reason for the subclass was to separate concerns.  I was planning on placing everything to do with state `TERMS` and state `ACCEPTTERMS` into the `Terms` class and methods for state `ANOTHER` and state `OPTIONS` into another class.  Failing this, my current `ServerProtocol` class would contain too many methods that perhaps should be separated for good practice.

Comment: Separation for separation's sake isn't a good practice--they're already tightly-coupled, because Terms is a subclass. If ServerProtocol is a state machine, then make it a state machine, and actually decouple the classes. As written it's more confusing than anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share the state member between two instances it would have to be static...

Comment: (I misread initially, although I'd change the wording to "two instances"--it's not that the `Terms` class doesn't have access to `state` (because it does), it's that it's a different instance.)

Comment: It is correct that `public static int state = TERMS` would make it work. But I think that having only one state in the entire JVM is not really a _good_ solution to the problem.

Comment: @extraneon If my solution is not a good one, how would you recommend I improve it?